# How can import a generated html file to a ionic framework project?

Tags: angular, ionic3, qgis

I need to import a generated html (with folders with resources like css and javascript) exported from qgis (maps) into a tab of my Ionic 3 app.

Here is the link to the generated html.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4zLZ_a0rtKNQ0g2VE15ZDRhaW8?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host it on a webserver and use an iframe to display the page. This will be *much* easier that integrating all those files into the ionic ecosystem.

What you can try though is to put the files in the `assets` folder of your project and then use an iframe to display the local `index.html`. Another possibility without an iframe is to add all the dependencies in the qgis `index.html` to the `index.html` of your project (you will have to change the paths) and then add the styles, html-tags, etc. to one of your ionic-pages but as I said - this will be tricky getting it to work as you want.